# Suppress warning “Access to field exceeds its access rights” in Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock, access-modifiers, suppress-warnings

I write a Groovy script and I need to access a field that has a private access modifier. This works fine but generates a warning:

`Access to <field_name> exceeds its access rights`

I want to supress this warning. What value of `@SuppressWarnings` annotation do I have to use in order to achieve it?

I've tried `@SuppressWarnings("all")` and it works fine but I would like to have more granular control over suppressions. I've also tried `@SuppressWarnings("AccessingNonPublicFieldOfAnotherObject")` but it has no effect.

Below how this warning looks in IntelliJ:

[image: Warning in IntelliJ]

Unfortunately automatic hint doesn't suggest any sensible solution:

[image: IntelliJ hints]

Comment: Where do you see that warning? On a compiler command line? If so, which compiler + version are you using, how are you calling the compiler? Or is is a warning shown in an IDE such as IntelliJ IDEA? Please be more specific. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be appreciated, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about IntelliJ warning:

[image]

then you can hit Alt+Enter on the offender and choose "Suppress for method" as follows:

[image]

after which you will see `@SuppressWarnings("GroovyAccessibility")` over your test method:

[image]

Comment: LOL, same time, same assumption - see my comment. That's why I was asking, too.

Comment: @kriegaex yeah I see :)

Comment: Thank you, @SuppressWarnings("GroovyAccessibility") did the job! Do you have any idea why I do not have the same hints as you? I have IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1

Comment: @k13i most likely, the "Access to inaccessible element" inspection is disabled. Try following the [IntelliJ Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#disable-inspections) to enable it. I'm able to reproduce your situation by unchecking this inspection

Comment: After using this, the warning is gone, but still I have an error of `Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(String, File)` . How come it can't get there? It's a very valid CTOR...

Answer (score 1):

I had this "problem" when I had buildSrc folder in Gradle-project which contained Kotlin code for my Gradle build scripts and it was used in Groovy code.

Seems like it was because I was accessing private variable field and not the getter. Kotlin makes field private by default. I solved this by using @JvmField in Kotlin code which makes the variable field public and does not generate getter for that field.

```
// groovy in gradle build script
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility(CompileOptions.javaVersion)
}

// kotlin in buildSrc (this gives the warning)
object CompileOptions {
    val javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
// kotlin in buildSrc (this does not give the warning as field is now public)
object CompileOptions {
    @JvmField val javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```